# redirecting to a new page when an html 5 audio file has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am playing an audiobook chapter with the text and want it to automatically redirect to a new page with the next chapter text and audio when the html5 audio file finishes.

I am not a programmer so I could use some help.

I know I need to use the addEventListener with the ended function similiar to what is below but I do not know how to modify this to call a new page instead of a new audio file.

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls src="song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
    this.src = "song2.mp3?nocache="+new Date().getTime();
    this.play();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ended` event and redirect:

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#event-media-ended

```
function redirectHandler() {
  window.location = 'http://example.com';
}

audio.addEventListener('ended', redirectHandler, false);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tqam3zyf/2/**

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
this.src = "song2.mp3?nocache="+new Date().getTime();
this.play();
```

you set the current source of the audio element.

If you want to load a new page instead of your current page you can use :

```
window.location = "your_url";
```